# Change the Load More "button" in three20 TTThumbsViewController?

Tags: iphone, three20

How can i change the custom three20 Load More footer in a TTThumbsViewController ?

Answer (score 3):

TTThumbsViewController is a fancy TTTableViewController which means he is using a TTDataSource. The best way on it is inheriting from TTThumbsViewController and Overriding this message (this is the one that TTThumbsViewController is using) :

```
- (id<TTTableViewDataSource>)createDataSource {
  return [[[TTThumbsDataSource alloc] initWithPhotoSource:_photoSource delegate:self] autorelease];
}
```

Then implement a datasource that inherits from TTThumbsDataSource and override this message like this:

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[TTTableMoreButton class]]) {
        return [YOU_CLASS class];
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
    } 
}
```

What happens behind the scenes is that the datasources decides if there are more images to load, if so it adds a TTTableMoreButton item to the list of items needed to be shown. By giving it your own cell class you can completely override the look and feel of that cell.